# danielgindi/Charts - iOS - Set Label above Specific bar on bar chart

Tags: swift, ios-charts

I am using danielgindi/Charts library for my iOS project in swift. Specifically, I am using bar charts where each day (x Axis) represents some value (y axis). I know we can Draw the values on each bar by setting the `setDrawValues` on chart data.

Instead of that value I need to show something else, Let's say I want to highlight today's bar by placing the "Today" label above the bar.

Could anyone please guide me how can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to display only one value "Today" or you want to change the value label for the particular bar only? Can you provide a visual example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the easiest way to solve your task is to use a custom value formatter. You can control which values will be visible or hidden. E.g.

```
import Charts

class MyValueFormatter: IValueFormatter {
    var xValueForToday: Double?  // Set a value

    func stringForValue(_ value: Double, entry: ChartDataEntry, dataSetIndex: Int, viewPortHandler: ViewPortHandler?) -> String {
        if entry.x == xValueForToday {
            return "Today"
        } else {
            return String(value)
        }
    }
}
```

and use it

```
myBarChartView.barData?.setValueFormatter(MyValueFormatter())
myBarChartView.barData?.setDrawValues(true)
```